# Weird python bug. Variable changes value without any modification

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the function "enText" changes its value even though I don't modify it.

e = 5 and n = 6. enText is an array of ints.
I modify the values in the array after passing it to changeTxt. I then return changeTxt but for some reason enText ends up being modified as well.

No idea why.

```
#Function for encryption
    def encrypt(e, n, enText):

        #e=5 & n=6
        changeTxt = enText

        print(enText)
        #prints [18, 15, 2, 9, 14]

        for x in range(0, len(changeTxt)):

            #problem here!!!!!!!!
            tmp = changeTxt[x]**e
            tmp = tmp % n
            changeTxt[x] = tmp

        print(enText)
        #prints [0, 3, 2, 3, 2]

        return changeTxt
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
changeTxt = enText
```

only copies the reference to the list, but both point to the same list. So changes to `changeTxt` will affect `enText` as well.

Instead try to clone the list like this:

```
changeTxt = enText[:]
```

or

```
changeTxt = list(enText)
```

Comment: Just did. Unfortunately I'm a new user so StackOverflow doesn't display my upvotes.